# Android Emulator output not forwarded thru SSH X11 forwarding

Tags: android-studio, qemu, x11-forwarding, android-emulator

I have managed to setup Android Studio with AVD and KVM on a host computer `myserver`.
From a client computer I now do `ssh me@myserver -X` and launch the andriod studio so that the UI is displayed on my client thru X11 forwarding.

This works flawlessly until I start an emulated  virtual Android device. I get the AVD UI and the Android divce displayed, but it's screen content remains black.
If I work locally on `myserver` instead of using X11 forwarding, the emulation works as expected and I get Android's screen display output.

Does the emulator do some special 'magic' output that surepasses the X11 forawarding? Any chance for me to get the Android display forwarded either?

I have tried setting Graphics to Software or Hardware on the virtual Android device, but there's no differenc, the screen remains black when launched through SSH tunnle.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this using VNC:

On `myserver` side:

```
cd $ANDROID_SDK/emulator
vncserver :2 -localhost no -geometry 540x760
export DISPLAY=:2
./emulator -avd Pixel3
```

On `client` side:

```
vncviewer myserver:5902
```

While I'd prefer to have a flawless UI integration this catches the android emulator screen without problem so that it's usable. I still hope to find options enabling direct X11 forwarding.